# Table name listing sql query help required

Tags: sql

I have a table Table_1 which has entries from 1 to 10 and I have 20 other tables which are using the values 1 - 10 in a column.
I want to list down all the table names which have entries where the corresponding entry in Table_1 is missing.

eg :

```
Table_1 has values 1- 10
Table_2 is using 2 and 5
Table_3 is using 7,9 and 28
Table_4 is using 2,7,9
Table_5 is using 7, 9,76
```

So the output of my query should give me table_3 and Table_5

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29   learn about those, and you'll be able to answer your own question.

Comment: I have read everything about joins but cant figure out how to list down the tablenames in my query output

Comment: a basic understanding of set theory is helpful as well. consider each table a circle in a Venn diagram, and you're looking for the part of table 2/3/4/5 that DOESN'T overlap table_1

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It is a project requirement and I have provided an example scenario. Suppose I have a source file table which has the entries for all source Fie IDs.  There are other tables like Contracts, Cancel_contracts etc and for each record in these tables there is a corresponding Source_NO. So When I do a distinct of source_No I get the diferent values that are present in the table.Now I want to list down the table name if it has any entry in Source_No colmn which is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TableName
FROM (SELECT 'Table_2' as TableName, col
      FROM Table_2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Table_3' as TableName, col
      FROM Table_3
      /*repeat for all tables*/
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Table_20' as TableName, col
      FROM Table_20) x
      LEFT JOIN Table_1 t ON x.col = t.col
WHERE t.col is NULL
```

Comment: This query works fine Thanks. But is there a way where I dont have to Hardcode all the table names and instead use a #table to list all the tables from sys.all_objects and retrive one row at a time? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not without using dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You can also use the minus and/or except set operators if you're using sql server / Oracle. Not sure what database you're using.

```
select 'in tbl 2 but not tbl 1' as which, numcol from table_2 where numcol not in (select numcol from table_1)
union all
select 'in tbl 3 but not tbl 1' as which, numcol from table_3 where numcol not in (select numcol from table_1)
union all
select 'in tbl 4 but not tbl 1' as which, numcol from table_4 where numcol not in (select numcol from table_1)
union all
select 'in tbl 5 but not tbl 1' as which, numcol from table_5 where numcol not in (select numcol from table_1)
```